# getting TypeScript error in reactjs with use of axios

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

I am using Axios for API in my react project but getting an error

> **C:/xampp/htdocs/invest19beta/src/Components/PersonList.tsx TypeScript error in
>   C:/xampp/htdocs/invest19beta/src/Components/PersonList.tsx(20,56):
>   Property 'name' does not exist on type 'never'.  TS2339**

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class PersonList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    persons: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(res => {
        const persons = res.data;
        this.setState({ persons });
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        { this.state.persons.map(person => <li>{person.name}</li>)}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: i am using Axios API @keikai

Comment: There are some `person` which don't have the attribute `name`, use `optional chaining` or `conditional operator` to set default value